# What is the purpose of options for models?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In the [Backbone API for Model](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-constructor)

the example only sets the attributes as an example.  As an optional second parameter you can set `options`.

I can't find anything in the API that explains this.  Also the source code does not make complete sense to me.

```
var Model = Backbone.Model = function(attributes, options) {
var attrs = attributes || {};
options || (options = {});
this.cid = _.uniqueId('c');
this.attributes = {};
if (options.collection) this.collection = options.collection;
if (options.parse) attrs = this.parse(attrs, options) || {};
attrs = _.defaults({}, attrs, _.result(this, 'defaults'));
this.set(attrs, options);
this.changed = {};
this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Are they only for setting `collection` and `parse`?  Why are they broken off an made separate from attributes?

Answer (score 0):

On the top of my head I can see 2 reasons:

1. options is not data everyting going to `attributes` can be accessed using `.get(attrName)`
2. `options` is also send though to the `.set` method.

And we havnt even talked about what is going on in the `initialize` method. You can use this to tons of cool stuff.

Answer (score 0):

options placeholder provides meta information needed to proceed in every methods. Mostly in the methods

1. validate()
2. sync()
3. parse()

such those...
For instance, in validate method the options returns...

```
{"validate":true}
```

In sync method the options returns...

```
{"validate":true,"parse":true}
```

In parse method the options returns...

```
{"validate":true,"parse":true,"emulateHTTP":false,"emulateJSON":false,"xhr":{"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"your-response-keys\" : \"your-response-values\"}","status":201,"statusText":"Created"}}
```

like that... In each method, it provides additional information 
to proceed next functionality.

Please note that, You don't have to set these properties at anytime. They are implicitly set by the
backbone library, to track the current instance's status.
Hope this helps you.